# Flutter uploading file to ubuntu server with dio ends in status error 405

Tags: flutter

I need to upload a file with an flutterapp to an folder on an ubuntu testserver using the Dio package.

```
class FileUploader {

  static Future uploadFile({String? filePath})async{
    try{
      final formData = FormData.fromMap({
        'name': 'dio',
        'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath!, filename: 'upload.jpg'),
        'files': filePath
      });
      final response = await Dio().post('http://h4053796.stratoserver.net', data: formData);
      print(response.data);

    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Iam getting this error: "DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 405."

I searched the error code, but i am not sure how to manage this error, does anybody has an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to check your server logs? error 405 is "not allowed" so I suppose you are trying to use post but your server doesn't allow that method to be used

Comment: Not really because iam not familiar with server that much, but i found the location with a lot of files, which one is the file i have to check out? Thanks